# how to update a range of html using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio-player

I am making a music player and thus wants that as song plays, the progress bar gets modify accordingly using jquery. But my progress bar isnt getting updated.

```
let myProgressBar = $('#myProgressBar');
audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate',()=>
{
    var progress= parseInt((audioElement.currentTime/audioElement.duration)*100);
    myProgressBar.value = progress;
});
```

above is the js code which i tried with.
and below is the html code of progress bar

```
 <input type="range" name="range" id="myProgressBar" min="0" value="0" max="100">
```

please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how you set a value with jQuery:

```
myProgressBar.value = progress;
```

[This is](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
myProgressBar.val(progress);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error because you are mixing jQuery and JavaScript. Here is the updated code:-

```
let myProgressBar = $('#myProgressBar');
audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate',()=>
{
    var progress= parseInt((audioElement.currentTime/audioElement.duration)*100);
    myProgressBar.val(progress);
});
```